# Invalid redirect error using zoom oauth2 and flutter_web_auth

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, zoom-sdk

I am trying to authenticate the user and followed all the instructions. Changed AndroidManifest scheme and the join function is provided below. How to solve this?

```
Future<void> onJoin() async {
    //setState(() {});
    final result = await FlutterWebAuth.authenticate(
      url:
          "https://zoom.us/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ZfyVB0fURFCcMywvpQOjxA&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdoorapp%3A%2F",
      callbackUrlScheme: "doorapp",
    );
    print(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out,

The error was code 4700. We had to whitelist the redirect url in the app marketplace. It worked after that

Comment: I've also been trying to use a https redirect like you. However, upon success it doesnt redirect to the app. Can I have a look at your manifest code?

Comment: Hi @limjix you can did it?